# What are the Disadvantages of Using "Var" inside the DAX Formula

Tags: powerbi, dax

Although the advantage of using "Var" is clear

1. It helps to keep the formula more readable.
2. It helps the user to return the output for every step.

What are the disadvantages of using Var declaration inside the Formula.

- Does it affect performance ?
- Does it affect calculation in any way ?
- Any other things to keep in mind ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of any disadvantages *per se*, but there are cases where people misuse them.

The most frequent mistake I see is where people mistake `VAR` simply as a shortcut for reusing code without understanding that it's a fixed value that is not affected by filter context. For example, in the following the `FILTER` has no effect on `Sum` since the variable is fixed.

```
VAR Sum = SUM( Table[Value] )
CALCULATE( Sum, FILTER( Table, <Condition> ) )
```

Another thing to keep in mind is if you have a series of large table-valued variables in a measure, your calculation might be less efficient or take more memory than it needs to if it were written differently. But this is highly case-specific and not really a disadvantage of variables so much as a consideration in implementation optimization.